# ContourPlot: format numbers in contour labels and legend

Tags: format

Can you suggest me a simple way to specify custom display format (for example ScientificForm) for such large values in contour labels and legend please?

Thank you!

```
k = 1.380648813 10^-23;(* Boltzmann constant*)

ContourPlot[1/(k T )  Log10[1 + Z]/Z,
 {T, 273, 330},
 {Z, 1, 50},
 ImageSize -> Large,
 FrameLabel -> {{"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"Z\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", None}, {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"T\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\",\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\" \",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)\!\(\*
StyleBox[\"K\",\nFontSlant->\"Italic\"]\)", None}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0], Bold},
 Contours -> Automatic,
 ContourLabels -> Automatic,
 PlotLegends -> Automatic
 ]
```

[image: contour plot with large numbers]

Comment: Could you please  provide code of above example, in order to permit the community to answer effectively ?

Comment: Why not simply define a new function to be $10^{-18}$ your current function?

Comment: I added the code. I cannot multiply the function by 10−18 because this multiplier can change by orders of magnitude. That is I want number format to be automatically adjusted in every case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `PlotLegends -> Automatic` by

```
PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
  LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 3}], Bold, Black, 12] &)]
```

to produce

[image]

Many other formats are possible, depending on what you are seeking.  (By the way, just ignore that `LabelingFunction` is in red in Mathematica.  It works anyway.)

**Addendum**

In answer to the question in the comment below, I suggest the following:

```
k = 1.380648813 10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant*)
T1 = 273; T2 = 330; rs = .1;
plt = ContourPlot[rs/(k T) Log10[1 + Z]/Z, {T, T1, T2}, {Z, 1, 50}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {Style["T, K", Italic], Style["Z", Italic]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 12}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ContourLabels -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
    Inset[Style[NumberForm[N[z/rs], {Infinity, 1}], Bold, 12], 
      {Piecewise[{{x + 3, x < T1 + 3}, {x - 3, x > T2 - 3}}, x], y}]], 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LabelingFunction -> 
    (Style[NumberForm[N[#/rs], {Infinity, 1}], Bold, Black, 12] &)]]
```

Unfortunately, it includes two "work-arounds".  First, a temporary rescaling, `rs` has been added to take account that `ContourPlot` does not pass `ContourLabels` of `10^19` or greater.  I shall look further into this idiosyncrasy.  Second, a `Piecewise` function has been added to better center the `ContourLabels`.

Additionally, `PlotRange -> All` has been added to recover the small portion of plot at the bottom and to improve the accuracy of the `BarLegend` labels. Labeling format also has been improved.

[image]

**Second Addendum**

As an alternative to adjusting the positions of `ContourLabels` for better centering, they can be allowed to extend outside the frame with the code

```
k = 1.380648813 10^-23;(*Boltzmann constant*)
T1 = 273; T2 = 330; rs = .1;
plt = ContourPlot[rs/(k T) Log10[1 + Z]/Z, {T, T1, T2}, {Z, 1, 50}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {Style["T, K", Italic], Style["Z", Italic]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Black, Bold, 12}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImagePadding -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False,
  ContourLabels -> Function[{x, y, z}, 
    Inset[Style[NumberForm[N[z/rs], {Infinity, 1}], Bold, 12], {x, y}]], 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, LabelingFunction -> 
    (Style[NumberForm[N[#/rs], {Infinity, 1}], Bold, Black, 12] &)]]
```

Alternatively, the frame can be made larger by replacing `ImagePadding -> All, PlotRangeClipping -> False,` by `PlotRangePadding -> 3.2,`.

**Third Addendum**

Jens' answer to [Question 79052](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79052/contourlabels-issues) can be used to eliminate the first "work-around" described above.

```
k = 1.380648813 10^-23; t1 = 273; t2 = 330; z1 = 1; z2 = 50;
f[t_, z_] := 1 Log10[1 + z]/(k t z)
plt = ContourPlot[f[t, z], {t, t1, t2}, {z, z1, z2}, 
  ImageSize -> Large, FrameLabel -> {Style["T, K", Italic], Style["Z", Italic]}, 
  LabelStyle -> {Bold, Black, 12}, PlotRange -> All,
  ContourLabels -> (Inset[Style[NumberForm[f[#1, #2], {Infinity, 1}], Bold, 12], 
        {Piecewise[{{#1 + 3, #1 < t1 + 3}, {#1 - 3, #1 > t2 - 3}}, #1], #2}] &), 
  PlotLegends -> BarLegend[Automatic, 
    LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 1}], Bold, Black, 12] &)]]
```

which yields a plot identical to the second one above.  A Comment by Simon Woods in [Question 79052](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79052/contourlabels-issues) also provides an alternative.

Comment: Super! Thank you very much!!! How does one do the same operation with contour labels?

Answer (score 3):

Replace PlotLegends-> Automatic with Barlegend combined with option LegendFunction

```
PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, LegendFunction -> (ScientificForm[# // N] &)]]
```

[image]