# ContourLabels issues

Tags: plotting, labeling

The `ContourPlot` generated by

```
k = 1.380648813 10^-23; T1 = 273; T2 = 330; 
plt = ContourPlot[.3/(k T) Log10[1 + Z]/Z, {T, T1, T2}, {Z, 1, 50}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ContourLabels -> All, PlotRangePadding -> 10]
```

(simplified from Question [78999](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/78999/contourplot-format-numbers-in-contour-labels-and-legend)) incorrectly lists the values of several contours as `0`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

From

```
Cases[plt, Text[z_, __] -> z, Infinity]
(* {2500000000000000000, 5000000000000000000, 7500000000000000000, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

it is evident that `ContourPlot` is not passing values equal to `10^19` or greater.

Is there any command or simple work-around to alleviate this problem (apart from dividing the first `ContourPlot` argument by some number `rs = 3` or greater and then replacing `ContourLabels -> All` by `ContourLabels -> Function[{x, y, z}, Inset[z*rs, {x, y}]]`?

Comment: The cut-off appears to be at ``Developer`$MaxMachineInteger``

Comment: Setting contours explicitly seems to fix it: `Contours -> FindDivisions[{0, 2*10^19}, 10]`

Comment: @SimonWoods  Thanks for your solution.  Please consider submitting it as an Answer, even if you do not care about the points, so that it has more visibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Labeling the contours in this case requires many digits, but becomes much more readable (I think) if scientific notation is used. To work around the incorrect chopping of the contour labels and also force *Mathematica* to use scientific notation, I would suggest the following:

```
plotFunction[T_, Z_] := .3/(k T) Log10[1 + Z]/Z

labelFunction = Text[plotFunction[#1, #2], {#1, #2}] &;

k = 1.380648813 10^-23; T1 = 273; T2 = 330;
plt = ContourPlot[plotFunction[T, Z], {T, T1, T2}, {Z, 1, 50}, 
  PlotRange -> All, ContourLabels -> {labelFunction, None}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> 10]
```

[image: contours]

This is a plot from version 8 (where a similar bug also appears, although it looks different from version 10). I checked that this works in version 10 as well.

What I did is to separately define the function to be plotted, so I can invoke it independently in the `ContourPlot` as usual, and also in the generation of the `ContourLabels` inside the plot. The latter makes it possible to re-calculate the correct function values when the contour label is drawn. The specification of the form `ContourLabels -> {labelFunction, None}` has as its first element the `labelFunction` that does this re-calculation and also wraps the output in a `Text` element. Here, `None` stands for the (unwanted) tooltip function.

Of course, there is still the issue of the awfully chosen default label placement. To get around this, you could look at [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9187/245).